# Why does it throws a Arg_ InvalidCastException when I cast a color resources in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I work on a project target on Windows Phone 7.5 and above.
I define a color resources in App.xaml and use it as a global resource.
And When I use it in code-behind, it throws me a error.

The Resource in XAML:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColor" Color="#FFF6F6F6"/>
```

The invoke in C#

```
    private void BuildApplicationBar()
    {
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
        ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"];
    }
```

The error happens when I try cast the resource:
[Arg_InvalidCastException]

> Arguments:  Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key
>   and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem.
>   See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.50829.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_InvalidCastException

***Why and how to resolve it, I did check that the type of AppBar's bgcolor is a Color,how could this happen when I do the cast?***

Comment: I think you are looking for SolidColorBrush.Color property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the resource as a `Brush`, yet you're casting it to `Color`. It can't possibly work.

Try this instead:

```
private void BuildApplicationBar()
{
    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = ((SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"]).Color;
}
```

Comment: you are my hero! But the wired thing is that my code previous worked in my personal app which build by VS2010 , WP7 SDK